# PGLS with interaction term in caper: "system is computationally singular"

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to compare two pgls models - one with an interaction, the other without it - in caper:

```
library(caper)
cdat <- comparative.data(data=dat, phy=MCC_genus_tree, names.col="taxa")
model_pgls<-pgls(LogSpecies~LogSubspecies, data=cdat)
model_interaction<-pgls(LogSpecies~LogSubspecies*Substrate, data=cdat)
```

However, when I run the interaction model, I get an error about the system being computationally singular:

```
Error in solve.default(xVix, tol = .Machine$double.eps) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.64018e-17
```

For context, "Substrate" is a binary variable (with 'terrestrial' coded as 1 and 'nonterrestrial' coded as 0).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with my tree - I re-ran the PGLS with a new tree (but the exact same data) and it ran fine.